# Auto-layout calculator

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to set the constraints of a course calculator that I made out of buttons but it's really hard to get the constraints right it just won't get the way I want it. This is how it looks in my storyboards and the ratio's are like I want it.

[image]

And this is how it turns up in an iPhone 4 simulator.

[image]

- The first column (except 0) has equal width to the third column (200)
- The second column is not equal to the rest (198)
- I am using size classes

I couldn't make all width's equal because I need the spacing in-between the buttons.

What would be the best way to set it's constraints?

Comment: When you say row, you mean column?

Comment: With row I mean the vertical rows in which number 1 is in row 1, number 2 in 2, and number 3 in 3.

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 are in the same row but in three different column.

Comment: Set width equal to parent with a multiplier of 1:3

Comment: And in the last row only set the multiplier to the "," button and nothing to the "0" button

Comment: And for the gaps (I guess you only want it to look like borders) you can just add borders to all your buttons using the buttons layers

Comment: Why do you want auto layout here? It is much easy to create container view with `layoutSubviews` implementation and do layout manually. It will be fast and easy to handle different width and height of Apple devices.

Comment: @JohnTracid I would want Autolayout here doing UI programmatically is lame :)

Comment: You could also use UICollectionView

Comment: I couldn't manage to do it with the multiplier it wouldn't work for me. So I set all buttons to width 200 instead. All I need to do now is to add the borders but I don't really understand the button layers thing. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the 3 button rows:

-Set constraint of the button 1 to the left side with value 0

-Set constraint of the button 3 to the right side with value 0

-Set the widths of the buttons 1,2 and 3 to be the same

-Set constraint of the button 1 to the button 2 with value >= 1

-Set constraint of the button 2 to the button 3 with value >= 1

And for the two buttons row, do the same, but set the width of button 0 to be 2:1 of the , button

Comment: Same as I commented on simardeep. I still need the borders in-between.

Comment: The constraints between the buttons will define the borders

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS9 and up, you can use Stack Views to make this in  a matter of minutes. You would use 5 stack views, one for each row, plus a sixth to contain the 5 rows in a vertical stack. Each horizontal stack can be set to fill equally. For the last row where you have a double width button, you can constrain the comma button to one from another row and allow the 0 to fill the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without looking at all the constraints. But still, as you are using buttons. Select all the buttons and give them EqualWidth and EqualHeight constraint. The buttons in center can be placed by "Horizontal center in container". The buttons on left only requires "Leading Edge" and "Top edge", while right side buttons require "Trailing edge" and "Top Edge"

Side by side check how these will look in other devices by opening Assistant Editor, then Automatic and then Preview.

Comment: This is what I am looking for but what about the borders?

Comment: Which borders are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

> apply first  1,2,3, buttons equal width if it works fine apply all buttons except zero

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers but the easiest way I could find actually fix my problem is this:

- Set all widths and heights equal (except 0)
- Give equal height and width constraint
- Edit first and last column to have 1px less width
- Update constraints

This way I was able to use equal width and height + keep borders/gaps